# How to group elements in array_chunk

Tags: php

I have a problem creating a module in joomla. My php skills are restricted. I use foreach to show elements in the template file:

```
<?php foreach ($filtered_array as $index=>$value) { ?>
   <div>show information></>
<?php } ?>
```

How can i use array_chunk to group 3 elements into one div and the next 3 into another?

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `array_chunk` as you told and a nested loop.

```
<?php foreach (array_chunk($filtered_array, 3) as $row): ?>
    <?php foreach ($row as $value): ?>
        <div>show information></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```